# Time complexity of regex and Allowing jitter in pattern finding

Tags: regex, string, r, pattern-matching, time-complexity

To find patterns in string, I have the following code. In it, find.string finds substring of maximum length subject to (1) substring must be repeated consecutively at least th times and (2) substring length must be no longer than len.

```
reps <- function(s, n) paste(rep(s, n), collapse = "") # repeat s n times

find.string <- function(string, th = 3, len = floor(nchar(string)/th)) {
    for(k in len:1) {
        pat <- paste0("(.{", k, "})", reps("\\1", th-1))
        r <- regexpr(pat, string, perl = TRUE)
        if (attr(r, "capture.length") > 0) break
    }
    if (r > 0) substring(string, r, r + attr(r, "capture.length")-1) else ""
}
```

An example for the above mentioned code: for the string "a0cc0vaaaabaaaabaaaabaa00bvw" the pattern should come out to be "aaaab".

NOW I am trying to get patterns allowing **jitter** of 1 character. Example: for the string "a0cc0vaaaabaaadbaaabbaa00bvw" the pattern should come out to be "aaajb" where "j" can be anything. Can anyone suggest a modification of the above mentioned code or any new code for pattern finding, that could allow such jitters?

Also can anyone throw some light on the **TIME COMPLEXITY** and **INTERNAL ALGORITHM** used for the regexpr function ?

Thanks! :)

Comment: You may have a look at `agrep`, which allows for "Approximate String Matching (Fuzzy Matching)".

Comment: The main problem you are likely to run into is that the TRE library does not appear to support approximate matching on backreferences (e.g. `\\1`), AFAIK.  This is unfortunate as otherwise a minor change to the above code would have resolved your problem (e.g. `rep("(\\1){ < 2}", th - 1)`.  Hopefully I'm wrong and there is a way to get this to work, but simple testing suggests it doesn't.  Also, note you can't use `perl=T` for approximate matching, so some other changes may be required.

Comment: The current answers do not contain enough detail? To me, it looks like they don't contain _any_ detail. Because they don't exist. :P

Comment: If there is any amount of "jitter", you might consider using a machine learning approach trained on an appropriate batch of data instead of regex matching.

Answer (score 1):

Not very efficient but tada:

```
reps <- function(s, n) paste(rep(s, n), collapse = "") # repeat s n times

find.string <- function(string, th = 3, len = floor(nchar(string)/th)) {
    found <- FALSE
    for(sublen in len:1) {
        for(inlen in 0:sublen) {
            pat <- paste0("((.{", sublen-inlen, "})(.)(.{", inlen, "}))", reps("(\\2.\\4)", th-1))
            r <- regexpr(pat, string, perl = TRUE)
            if (attr(r, "capture.length")[1] > 0){
                found = TRUE
                break;
            }
        }
        if(found) break
    }
    if (r > 0) substring(string, r, r + attr(r, "capture.length")[1] - 1) else ""
}

find.string("a0cc0vaaaabaaadbaaabbaa00bvw"); # returns "aaaab"
```

Without any fuzzy matching tool available, I manually check each possibility. I use an inner loop to try different size prefix and suffix lengths on either size of the "jitter" character. The prefix is grouped as `\2` and the suffix as `\4` (the jitter is `\3` but I don't use it). Then, the repeated part tries to match `\2.\4` - so the prefix, any new jitter character, and the suffix.

I say not efficient because its evaluating `O(len^2)` different patterns, versus `O(len)` patterns in your code. For large `len` this might become a problem.

Note that I have multiple groups, and only look at the [1] position. The full r variable has more useful information, for example [1] will be the first part, [5] will be the 2nd part, [6] will be the 3rd part, etc. Also [3] will be the "jitter" character in the 1st part.

---

Regarding the complexity of the actual regex: it varies a lot. However, often the construction (setup) of a particular regex is vastly more intensive then the actual matching, which is why a single pattern used repeatedly can produce better results than multiple patterns. In truth, this varies a lot based on the pattern and the engine you're using - see links at the end for more info about complexity.

Regarding how regex works: just a note, this is going to be a very theoretical overview, its not meant to indicate how any particular regex engine works.

For a more practical overview, there are plenty of sites that cover just enough to know how to use a regex, but not how to build your own engine. - for example http://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html

Regex is what's known as a state machine, specifically a (non-deterministic) finite state automaton (NFA). A very simple, real world state machine is a lightbulb: its either on, or off, and different inputs can change the state its in. A regex is much more complex, (generally) each symbol in the pattern forms a state, and different input can send it to different states. So if you have `\d\d\d`, 3 virtual states each can accept any digit, and any other input goes to a 4th "failure" state. The end result is the end state after all input is 'consumed'.

Perhaps you can imagine: this gets vastly more complicated, with many many states, when you use any ambiguity, such as wildcards or alternation. So our `\d\d\d` regex will basically be linear. But more complicated one will not be. Part of the optimization in a regex engine is converting a NFA to a DFA - a deterministic finite state automaton. Here, the ambiguity is removed, generating many more states, and this is the very computationally complex process referenced above (the construction stage).

This is really just a very theoretical overview of an ideal NFA. In practice, modern regex grammars can do a lot more than this, for example backtracing is not technically possible in a "proper" regex.

This might be a bit too high-level, but thats the basic idea. If you're curious, there are plenty of good articles about regex, different flavors, and their complexity. For example: http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html

Answer (score 0):

There's basically two regex algorithm types, Perl-Style (with a lot of complex backtracking) and Thompson-NFA.

http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html

To determine which engine R uses R's svn repo is here:

*root repo:
http://svn.r-project.org/R/

http://svn.r-project.org/R/branches\R-exp-uncmin\src\regex

I poked around in there a bit and found a file called "engine.c"  On first glance it doesn't look like a Thompson-NFA but I didn't take long to read it.

At any rate, the first link goes in depth into the complexity question in general and should give you a great idea as to how regex parsing works under the hood to boot.